# How to exclude test util from final build of nextjs

Tags: next.js, react-testing-library

I use the test util file in my next project. After building and installing by yarn install --prodction, I have a message error 'can not found '@testing-library/react' on the browser. While this is dev dependency and I did not use it inside pages.

Comment: Are you certain you're not importing `@testing-library/react` anywhere in your client code?

Comment: I found the problem. I exported testUtils into the utils index.ts file and use index.ts in another place. So by removing the export line from index.ts I fixed the error.